# C++ Is it legal to declare pointers and array on the same line?

Tags: c++

The following code works but I have been told that it doesn't compile with gcc 3.4.2 with Visual C++ 2010 and may be illegal:

```
int ar1[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    *ptr1 = ar1,
    ar2[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18},
    *ptr2 = ar2;
```

Apparently you need to make some modifications for it to work (something like that):

```
int ar1[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int *ptr1 = ar1;
int ar2[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18};
int *ptr2 = ar2;
```

Is that right? Can't arrays and pointers be declared together?

(The code compiles fine on QT + gcc 4.8)

Comment: Why do you need something like this?

Comment: This is C++11 code.  gcc 3.4.2 would be too old to recognize it.

Comment: @Caesar Actually I was doing an exercise for the book I'm reading. I know it is not necessary for a real application.

Comment: @VaughnCato Thanks, it explains. But is it legal according to the new standard?

Comment: @2013Asker I guess it is a free world and you can do what you like, but just so you know this is the type of code that would get you beat up by your co-workers in the parking lot after work.

Comment: Visual C++ 2010 doesn't support uniform initialziation either. Nor does VS2012; 2013 Preview reportedly does.

Comment: @2013Asker: yes (FWIW, the standard term is "well formed" rather than "legal", but whatever).

Comment: FWIW, I look upon declaration as a setting aside of memory for a variable and defining what type the variable is. In that sense arrays and pointers should be able to be declared together. However, whether arrays and pointers should be able to both be declared and assigned values on the same lines would seem to be a slightly different question. If one says the answer to that should be yes, I would want then to ask the question as to whether the question as to whether parsing must occur right to left on the line should be required or should we make it work in either direction.

Comment: @Caesar I think you got me wrong, I just needed the code to test a function.

Answer (score 15):

The declaration in question uses C++11 initialization syntax. It is not syntactically correct from the point of view of pre-C++11 compiler. But if you add a `=` before each `{` it will become ordinary and perfectly legal C++98 declaration (and C declaration as well).

There's no problem in using several declarators in one declaration, even if you mix pointer and array declarators. You can add function declarators into that mix, if you wish. The only restriction is that you can't embed function *definitions* in there.